# Help me to understand this conversion (4-vectors)

Tags: general-relativity

$u^{\mu}$ - 4-velocity

$b^{\mu}$ - 4-vector of magnetic field

$
u_{\mu}u^{\mu}=-1, \qquad u_{\mu}b^{\mu}=0
$

$$
u_{\beta}u^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}b^{\beta}-u_{\beta}b^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}u^{\beta}+\nabla_{\alpha}b^{\alpha}=0
$$
I don't understand why this equation gives this
$$
u^{\alpha}u^{\beta}\nabla_{\alpha}b^{\beta}+\nabla_{\alpha}b^{\alpha}=0
$$

Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

This is because $u_\alpha \nabla_\beta u^\alpha =0$. To show this, just act with $\nabla_\beta$ on both sides of the equality $u_\alpha u^\alpha = -1$. You get
$$
u_\alpha \nabla_\beta u^\alpha + u^\alpha \nabla_\beta u_\alpha = 0
$$
and thus $u_\alpha \nabla_\beta u^\alpha =0$ as promised.

Cheers!

Comment: You are correct, but perhaps use different indices (for consistency with the original question) and note the term $u_{\beta}b^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}u^{\beta}$ vanishes because $u_{\beta}\nabla_{\alpha}u^{\beta}=0$?

Comment: Exactly. Actually the names for the indicies does not really matter as long as your are consistent with yourself. Moreover, it is obvious that if $u_\alpha \nabla_\beta u^\alpha=0$, then of course $u_\beta \nabla_\alpha u^\beta=0$.